# When doing Java string comparison what values for ~ (tilda) hold?

Tags: java, string

For example:

```
public static void smallestWord() {
    String smallestWord = "~";
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    words.add("dba");
    words.add("dba");
    words.add("eba");
    words.add("dca");
    words.add("eca");

    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.compareTo(smallestWord) < 0) {
            smallestWord = word;

        }
    }
}
```

It returns `dba` as smallest word which is correct, but I initialized smallestWord as `~` initially, if I leave it as empty or `.` I do not get the correct answer. What value does `~` hold in Java lexicography?

Comment: Have a look at a ascii table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All characters in Java are compared by their Unicode codepoint. `~` is U+007E (126) in Unicode, which as larger than all the standard ASCII Latin characters, but less than characters from all other scripts, or accented Latin characters. For more detailed information on how strings are compared, you can read [the `String.compareTo` JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-).

What you want to do is probably rather something like this:

```
public static void smallestWord() {
    String smallestWord = null;
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    words.add("dba");
    words.add("dba");
    words.add("eba");
    words.add("dca");
    words.add("eca");

    for (String word : words) {
        if ((smallestWord == null) || (word.compareTo(smallestWord) < 0)) {
            smallestWord = word;
        }
    }
}
```

Or, alternatively, use the standard library:

```
Collections.min(words);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out `'~'` is an ASCII character / Unicode codepoint that is larger than all ASCII letters; i.e. upper and lowercase 'A' through 'Z'.

Therefore, according to the specification<sup>1</sup> of the `String` class, `"~"` comes after any English word.

However, the `'~'` codepoint is NOT less than accented letters and letters in non-latin alphabets.  So the `"~"` trick won't work with Cyrillic or Hindi.  And if you can think of a French / German / Portuguese / etc word that has an accented first letter, it won't work in those languages either.

And it won't work with Emojis either.

In short, that code using `"~"` as in your example won't work in internationalized contexts.

You could use `null` as per @Dolda2000's answer, or you could use `"\u10ffff"`.

(`\u10ffff` is the largest possible Unicode codepoint.  However that approach is not entirely fool-proof either.  There are legal Java strings that are larger than "\u10ffff"; e.g. "\u10ffffZZZZ".  Unfortunately, the largest possible string value cannot be written as a string literal, and its representation is ridiculously large - roughly 2^31 bytes!)

---

<sup>1 - The ordering of strings is based on the ordering of UTF-16 code units rather than Unicode codepoints.  But for well-formed strings there is no difference in the two ways of thinking about it.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

compareTo works unicode character value, ~ has unicode value greater than the alphabets so it works while space and dot has unicode value less than alphabets so it consider them as small and print the same.